# How do I create Custom bug detector for any know Static code review of tool?

Tags: checkstyle, findbugs, pmd, static-code-analysis

I have following classes. I can solve this issue by re-designing but this is legacy code so I can't change it.

Now, I can't review code written by all our junior developers but I want to create a custom bug detector for any static code review tool (Checkstyle, PMD or Findbugs) which will detect this kind of bugs in our Jenkins.

I have this interface **DataService**

```
public interface DataService {
    public void discard();
}
```

**MyDataService** classe implements this interface.

```
public class MyDataService implements DataService {

    public void discard() {
          //Some code here
    }
}
```

Test class.

```
public class Test {
    Service service
    public Test(Service service) {
         this.service = service;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataService internalDataService = service.getInternalDataService();
        DataService threadLocalDataService = service.getThreadLocalDataService();


        // Developer must invoke this method before leaving this block.
        // If he forgets then it should be reported as bug like 'resource leaking or something'. 
        internalDataService.discard();

        // This should be reported as bug because programmer shouldn't
        //invoke discard method of DataService when it is threadlocal.
        threadLocalDataService.discard();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is possible with findbugs. Search google for tutorials of how to create custom bug detectors...

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the first part (report forgotten discard calls) with PMD using the [Close Resource](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/pmd-java/rules/java/design.html#CloseResource) rule. This rule can be adjusted to verify `DataService` and `discard` using the following custom ruleset:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="ExampleRuleset"
         xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

    <description>
        discard as close resource target
    </description>

    <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/CloseResource">
        <properties>
            <property name="types" value="DataService"/>
            <property name="closeTargets" value="discard"/>
        </properties>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

More on how to create a custom ruleset: [How to make a custom ruleset](http://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.4.1/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html).

Save this ruleset as file e.g. `custom-ruleset.xml` and use it when executing PMD:

```
bin/run.sh pmd -d sourceDirectory -f text -R custom-ruleset.xml
```

You should see the violations, if you uncomment the "discard" calls, e.g.

```
src/Test.java:8:   Ensure that resources like this DataService object are closed after use
```

This however doesn't detect, that discard *should not be called* if the service is thread local...

Comment: Thanks @adangel for suggestion. I will try this and let you know if it works !